# Interpretability of meta-regression of proportions with multilevel covariates

Tags: r, modeling, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I'm interested in the possibility of a particular meta-analysis, but I have some reservations regarding its feasibility and would like clarity before investing the time in the analysis.

**Context:**
My field has many different tests requiring someone to read specific words out loud. Responses are scored as correct or incorrect, and a common summary measure for a word's difficulty is the proportion of people who answered correctly to the total sample size. Each test is usually between 20 and 50 words. The question to be answered by the meta-analysis is *what word traits (e.g., concreteness, age of acquisition, frequency of word in English) predict its difficulty*. There are obviously some other covariates of importance (e.g., age, years of education, English language preference), and these would also be included.

**Problem:**
While all tests are in English, they have no overlapping words. Additionally, each test is a little different in its constraints (e.g., timed vs. untimed, stop the test after X number of incorrect responses). As I currently conceptualize the meta-analysis, there are multiple levels of clustering and predictors: English words nested in tests that are nested in studies (though there can obviously be other clusters -- studies nested in authors/labs for example). I'm also concerned by the number of potential predictors in the meta-regression since I would be interested in multiple word-characteristics for each word, a few indicator variables for different test qualities, and then study-level covariates (e.g., average age, average years of education). Finally, I'm not sure whether the sampling errors should be considered correlated or not (and correlation matrices for that are likely not going to be reported).

**Questions:**
As I said, I'm primarily interested in whether this idea is possible and/or what it's limitations would be. I'm not aware of any meta-analyses that have looked at pooling data to analyze individual stimuli features, but if something similar has been done then please comment the reference. I know how I would do this if I had access to the raw data, but unfortunately, I really only have the potential for trying to pool these results from published studies right now. I would prefer to utilize the `rma.mv` function in `metafor`, if possible because I'm familiar with it; however, other R solutions would be welcomed.